# AES encryption on images

Tags: encryption, aes, watermark, steganography, cbc-mode

```
from hashlib import md5
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        password = key.encode('utf-8')
        self.key = md5(password).digest()

    def encrypt(self, data):
        vector = b'0123456789ABCDEF'
        # vector = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
        # .encrypt(pad(message, BLOCK_SIZE))
        encryption_cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, vector)
        return vector + encryption_cipher.encrypt(pad(data,  AES.block_size))

    def decrypt(self, data):
        file_vector = data[:AES.block_size]
        decryption_cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, file_vector)
        return  unpad(decryption_cipher.decrypt(data[AES.block_size:]),  AES.block_size)
```

i have this block of code for AES encryption,if i change the length of key does that mean if i take key length of 16 bytes it will automatically perform AES128 and vice-versa?

Comment: S. the PyCryptodome documentation for [`AES.new()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html#Crypto.Cipher.AES.new): *key (bytes/bytearray/memoryview) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes long (respectively for AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256).*

Comment: @Topaco yeah got it tried finding the size of key in __init__, it led me to know the answer